# How to use your own methods on arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void arrayReader(Fractions[] array)
    {
        System.out.println("This array has " + array.length + " elements");
        for(int count = 0; count < array.length; count++)
        {
            System.out.println("For cell number " + (count+1));
            array[count] = new Fractions();
            array[count].read();
        }
```

This is a portion of the code that I wrote. I was told to do the same thing except using ArrayList instead of arrays. So i ran into a problem. how would I be able to do array[count].read();

I tried this but it wouldn't work:

```
public static void readArray(ArrayList<Fractions> array)
    {
        System.out.println("This array has " + array.size() + " elements");
        for(int count = 0; count < array.size(); count++)
        {
            Fractions fraction = new Fractions();
            fraction.read();
            array.set(count, new Fractions());
            array.add(fraction);
        }
    }
```

I'm not trying to have you do my homework, I'm genuinly stuck. So please help me understand how this could work.

Comment: HOW didn't it work? Be specific

Comment: Why do you add a fraction and set a fraction? This is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, i actually got rid of the set and forgot to take it out when i posted it.

Comment: @TeneCursum when i try to output the code. it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all:**

```
 array[count] = new Fractions();
```

**is not equivalent to:**

```
 array.set(count, new Fractions());
 array.add(fraction);
```

the `arraylist.set` method:

```
Replaces the element at the specified position in this list
 with the specified element.
```

the `arrayList.add` method:

```
Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
```

**Use only**:

```
array.add(fraction);
```

**Then the for cycle is different**

If your are doing:

```
array = new ArrayList(5); //initial capacity

 for(int count = 0; count < array.size(); count++)
```

*the size is 0.*

If you are doing:

```
array = new Fractions[5]; //size

 for(int count = 0; count < array.size(); count++)
```

*the size is 5*.

Comment: You have to change the cycle for(int count = 0; count < array.size(); count++) .

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. I tried this and it wouldn't work.                                                    ArrayList<Fractions> array = new ArrayList<Fractions>(5);                                  Isn't this syntactically correct?

Comment: when i checked the size of the array it would return 0.

Comment: It is not correct. It is the initial capacity not the size. It is different from the array. Check the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)

Just updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. That was informative, I get it now.

Comment: Yes definitely this whole explanation gives the complete solution. What I put was just how to replace those two lines with working ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
array.add(count, new Fractions());
```

The line above is equivalent to the following line in previous code

```
array[count] = new Fractions();
```

That is adding the new Fractions() at a specific index in the ArrayList.

Similarly for the other line

```
array[count].read();
```

you will have

```
(array.get(count)).read();
```

Comment: my problem is with the next line. What would be the equivalent to array[count].read();

Comment: You can use like i mentioned above. Or you can do it like this too. Fractions fractions = array.get(count); fractions.read();